# how to query several MYSQL tables in one statement

Tags: mysql

There are 30 tables(categories) all with the same structure storing news items with a siteID field to filter on a particular client.
The client select which tables(categories) they show by setting the field visible(tinyint) field to 1 or 0.

I have the following test MYSQL which works okay. I am using Applicationcraft.com so the syntax is different than standard MYSQL but you can see the query.

```
function _getAllData(cObj,p){
var result = [];
console.log('started');
selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolNews').order('newsIDDESC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID);
result[0] = cObj.exec(selectObj); 
selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolDocs').order('newsIDASC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID);
result[1] = cObj.exec(selectObj);

return result;
}
```

So I have an array with the results of each table in result[0] & result[1].

So I created the following to :

```
function _getAllData(cObj,p){

var result = [];

console.log('started');

selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolNews').order('newsIDDESC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID).where('visible=?',1);

result[0] = cObj.exec(selectObj); 
selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolDocs').order('newsIDASC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID).where('visible=?',1);

result[1] = cObj.exec(selectObj);  
selectObj=Obj.select().from('schoolNews_copy').order('newsIDDESC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID).where('visible=?',1);

result[2] = cObj.exec(selectObj);
selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolNews_copy').order('newsIDDESC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID).where('visible=?',1);

result[3] = cObj.exec(selectObj);
selectObj=cObj.select().from('schoolNews_copy').order('newsIDDESC').where('siteID=?',p.siteID;
result[4] = cObj.exec(selectObj).where('visible=?', 1);
```

upto result[30].

I have populated schoolNews_copy with 1000 records and run the query from my app.

I am getting a timed out error.

Is this because.

1. query the same table causes the problem.
2. This is the wrong approach all together.
   If not what is the best approach.

Is there a way to query every table in a single statement and populate the results into an array named results.

So the result I need is an example array :

result[0] has data visible set to 1
result[1] has data visible set to 1
result[2] has data visible set to 0

Comment: Why would you split it up into 30 tables?! Why not 1 table with a "category" field linked to a category table?

Comment: Also, what framework are you using to do the database stuff? Where does cObj come from?

Comment: A) **DO NOT** split this up into separate tables, querying a single one is a million times easier. B) Please, don't post part of your question as an external resource. Over time these will become non-functional and your question will end up meaningless.

Comment: FYI, I brought your code back over from the text file that you were having trouble posting. I cleaned it up a little, someone else may want to tackle the grammar.

Comment: I am using www.applicationcraft.com this is their syntax for the their server side javascript. I pass over an array p in this case p.siteID. Also for future what did you do to clean the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have now restructured the table as you said. And using joins can get all the info I need in one query.

SELECT * FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `allNews` on allNews.catID = categories.catID WHERE  categories.visible = 1 AND categories.siteID = '+p.siteID;

MrWarby.